# To get notification to email when they are unprocessed folders in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, storage

I am beginner to GCP, I want to have two folders processed and unprocessed folder
in the cloud storage bucket. whenever a files comes to the google storage bucket from any source, after which cloud function will get triggered, if the files are successfully inserted into the target such as Bigquery, the file will go into the processed folder, if not into the unprocessed folder.
I want to know how can I get alerts when the files go into the unprocessed folder or error folder??

Do I have to write a code or Should I write  a cloud function or anything else which gets me alerts??

Any help will be appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned usage of Cloud Functions is the right approach.
A simple function is required, then it should be deployed with the proper trigger associated with a bucket.

More details, with examples can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage